# Public static method is not importing from src.test.java packet to src.main.java packet

Tags: java, packet

[image: my screenshot]([![https://prnt.sc/nj6ec2]

Why public static method from class of src.test.java packet is not importing to classes of src.main.java ?

When I print `MainTest` in classes of src.main.java packet, the IDE can't recognize it

Comment: Why are you trying to use code from a test in the main implementation? You shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and methods in `src/test/java` are intended for testing **only**. You should never attempt to use these in any code that is in `src/main/java` which should only contain code that is part of the app.